# Instances of deleted questions visible to users with <10k rep via suggested edit history

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, deleted-questions

This is a deleted question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944472/iam-doing-scroll-view-programmtically-but-not-able-to-scroll-the-images-program

I don't have 10k rep on Stack Overflow yet, but I can see that question (well, a revision of it, perhaps not the latest one) by looking at [an old suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/511443).

I know this isn't a major leak, since there's no handy interface for old suggested edits or any way to find suggested edits to a given post/user, but it's still a hole in the 10k wall.

Comment: "I'am doing scroll view programmtically but not able to scroll the images programmatically" That son of a.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn ?